# Erasing old git commits to enlighten a repo

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

I have an xcode project saved into a git repository on bitbucket, 
working for several months and changing several libs my .git file now weights 90MB

if i know that i would never need again some old lib like a 18MB Google SDK1.3 is there a way of removing them forever?

Answer (score 1):

Try git gc [it's various options are detailed here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

should help you. Its removing sensitive data but the principal is the same